# Magento 2.3 add body class to product page if custom options

Tags: magento2.3, product-page, class

I want to add a body class `"custom-options"` to the product page, when the product got some custom options.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

**Admin -> catalog -> Product -> Design -> Layout Update XML**

Add following code :

```
<body>
    <attribute name="class" value="custom-options" />
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I want this an all product pages with custom options, how can I achieve that?